# Video upload on s3 using nodejs and aws-sdk

Tags: node.js, express, amazon-s3, functional-programming

Im uploading videos on s3 using express-fileupload ,aws-sdk and s3.upload() function, The problem is some of my videos gets uploaded and s3 returns the url but when i try to play that video it's not playing and in some cases if the duration if greater than let say 5 mins the video gets stuck at 2 min or less. I've been searching this solution but unable to find any. I'm using node.js, express, and functional programming paradigm.

Here's my code for uploading both image and video

```
import aws from "aws-sdk";
const config = require(`${__dirname}/../config/config.js`);
const fs = require('fs');

const bucketName = config.s3.bucket_name;
const region = config.s3.bucket_region;
const accessKeyId =  config.s3.access_key;
const secretAccessKey =  config.s3.secret_key;
import csv from "csvtojson";
import path from "path";
import APP_CONSTANTS from "../constants/app.constant";

aws.config.update({
  region,
  accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey,
});

const s3 = new aws.S3();


const uploadFile = async (file,type) => {
  let fileName = null;
  let contentType = getFileContentType(file);
  switch(type) {
    case "banner":
      fileName = `banner/${Date.now()}-${file.name}`
      break;
    case "workout":
      fileName = `workout/${Date.now()}-${file.name}`
      break;
    case "calories":
      fileName = `csv/calories/${Date.now()}-${file.name}`
      break;
    case "videos":
      fileName = `videos/${Date.now()}-${file.name}`
      break;
    case "workout-videos":
      fileName = `workout/videos/${Date.now()}-${file.name}`
      break;
    case "daily_tasks":
      fileName = `daily_tasks/${Date.now()}-${file.name}`
      break;
    case "content":
      fileName = `content_of_the_day/${Date.now()}-${file.name}`
      break;
    case "customer":
      fileName = `customer/${Date.now()}-${file.name}`
      break;
    case "content_of_the_day":
      fileName = `content_of_the_day/${Date.now()}-${file.name}`
      break;
    default :
      fileName = `default/${Date.now()}-${file.name}`
      break;
  }

  // Setting up S3 upload parameters
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucketName,
    Key: fileName, // File name you want to save as in S3
    Body: file.data,
    ContentType: contentType
  };
  // Uploading files to the bucket
  const data = await s3.upload(params).promise();
  data.fileName = fileName;
  return data
};
const getFileContentType = (file ) => {
  let contentType = null;
  const extensionName = path.extname(file.name);
  if(APP_CONSTANTS.ALLOWED_IMAGE_EXTENSIONS.includes(extensionName)) {
    contentType = 'image/'+ extensionName.split('.').join('')
  }
  if(APP_CONSTANTS.ALLOWED_VIDEO_EXTENSIONS.includes(extensionName)) {
    contentType = 'video/'+ extensionName.split('.').join('')
  }
  return contentType
}

const s3Bucket = { getImage, uploadFile, getCsv };
export default s3Bucket;
```

Comment: how are you playing the video?

Comment: The url returned by s3.upload function i paste that in the browser and it starts playing the video since I don't have any ACL